# Generate number but exclude one number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to generate one random number between a range but exclude one specific number.
I thought I can do this like that but it didn't work.

```
function randNum(num){
    var randNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*num)+1;
    if(randNumber==2){
        randNum(num);
    }else{
        alert(num);
    }
}
randNum(4);
```

What is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You're passing "num" to `alert()` instead of "randNumber" ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typographical error.

Comment: better way: generate a number from 1 to 3. If it is `>=2`, add one. No need to loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to output the random number and not the `num`-parameter, you just have to change the alert to:

```
alert(randNumber)
```

Like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3urFC/

Comment: Little typing mistake.. Thanks. =]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to alert the randNum that you generated?  Right now you will alert the function argument (in this case the number 4) everytime.  I think you want to change it to alert(randNumber).

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random` returns a number between 0 and 1. See [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Also, [see this question about generating a random number in a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527820/54378).

So, you have two problems: one, you're not generating a random number in the range you think you are, and two, you're not using the random number you generated.

I [made this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/pbS6L/) that does something similar to what you described.

```
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function generateRandomWithExclusion(exclude, min, max) {
    var num = getRandomInt(min, max);

    while (num === exclude) {
        num = geRandomInt(min, max);   
    }

    return num;
}

generateRandomWithExclusion(2, 0, 10) // returns an integer between 0 and 10 that is not 2
```

You pass the number you want to exclude and a range of `min` and `max`, and get a random integer in that range that isn't the number you want excluded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typho as other has stated.

Also I would rearrange it this way:

```
function randNum(num){
    var numberToExclude=2;
    var randNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*(num-1))+1;

    if(randNumber>=numberToExclude) {
        randNumber+=1;
    }

    alert(randNumber);
}
randNum(4);
```

Here is a JSFidle

http://jsfiddle.net/2F5Md/1/

Comment: This is not a uniform distribution.

Comment: Asking for proof is a bit odd, but to explain, this will be twice as likely to pick 3 than most other numbers. Try running it a few hundred times and see for yourself. The method I suggested in the comments of the question gives an unbiased distribution.

Comment: I corrected the code.

Comment: Still not right. You need to use `>=` and have a special case for `num<2`. And you don't need the inner check for `>num` if you do it correctly.

Comment: Here is a correct implementation which has a lot of flexibility and covers all edge cases. It also includes a testing function to prove that it is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/bpsVR/1/

Comment: Small update for NaNs: http://jsfiddle.net/bpsVR/2/

Comment: For comparison, here is your function in the same type of test: http://jsfiddle.net/DXXe5/

Comment: @Dave: yes, I need to use >= Apart of this the code works. Check http://jsfiddle.net/2F5Md/

Comment: yes, that change does indeed fix it (http://jsfiddle.net/DXXe5/1/), although you still don't need the `>num` check.

Comment: yes Dave, no need for the >num check. You're right again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function randNum(num) {
    var randNumber;
    do { randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*num)+1; } while(randNumber==2);
    return randNumber;
}
randNum(4);
```